# R - find all possible pairwise date overlaps

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am working with a dataset which shows the temporal availability of observed data for multiple meteorological stations:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/fih7e2o8hrnewx7/dat.csv?dl=1") # ~43 KB

> dat
        ID  startdate    enddate
   1:  193 2000-01-01 2003-12-02
   2:    1 2000-01-01 2006-12-03
   3:    2 2000-01-01 2006-12-03
   4:    4 2000-01-01 2006-12-03
   5:    5 2000-01-01 2006-12-03
  ---                           
1631: 1277 2017-05-01 2019-11-09
1632: 1300 2017-05-01 2019-11-09
1633: 1321 2017-05-01 2019-11-09
1634: 1248 2017-05-06 2018-06-21
1635: 1265 2017-05-08 2019-12-18
```

What I need is to find the overlapping dates for all possible ID pairs. Based on the feedback to my previous question ([R - find overlapping dates per group based on another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460942/r-find-overlapping-dates-per-group-based-on-another-data-frame/60461090)), this is what I've tried so far:

```
# convert character to dates
cols <- c("startdate","enddate")
dat[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = cols]

# perform overlapping join
# i.e. find common dates for each station pair
setkey(dat, startdate, enddate)
olap <- unique(foverlaps(dat, dat)[ID!=i.ID, .(
  ID1=pmin(ID, i.ID),
  ID2=pmax(ID, i.ID),
  common_date_begin=pmax(startdate, i.startdate),
  common_date_end=pmin(enddate, i.enddate))])

> olap
          ID1  ID2 common_date_begin common_date_end
      1:    1  193        2000-01-01      2003-12-02
      2:    2  193        2000-01-01      2003-12-02
      3:    4  193        2000-01-01      2003-12-02
      4:    5  193        2000-01-01      2003-12-02
      5:    6  193        2000-01-01      2003-12-02
     ---                                            
1270379: 1248 1300        2017-05-06      2018-06-21
1270380: 1265 1300        2017-05-08      2019-11-09
1270381: 1248 1321        2017-05-06      2018-06-21
1270382: 1265 1321        2017-05-08      2019-11-09
1270383: 1248 1265        2017-05-08      2018-06-21
```

At first, it seems to be what I wanted. However, there are some pairs that do not appear in the resulting data table, although they do have overlapping periods of time. Some examples are:

```
> olap[ID1==997 & ID2==872]
Empty data.table (0 rows and 4 cols): ID1,ID2,common_date_begin,common_date_end

> olap[ID1==997 & ID2==785]
Empty data.table (0 rows and 4 cols): ID1,ID2,common_date_begin,common_date_end
```

But note that in the original dataset the above ID's do have overlapping dates:

```
> dat[ID==997]
    ID  startdate    enddate
1: 997 2000-03-01 2017-01-22
> dat[ID==872]
    ID  startdate    enddate
1: 872 2000-03-01 2019-08-09
> dat[ID==785]
    ID  startdate    enddate
1: 785 2000-03-01 2019-12-31
```

What I am doing wrong? Am I missing any arguments in `foverlaps`?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine, but the order of the IDs in your subset is backward. Try `olap[ID1==872 & ID2==997]`.

Comment: welcome to SO. Good catch! You have my vote as your first vote on SO :)